# How does a front end authentication for restricted views work in modern FE framworks like Vue (ft. nuxt) etc.?

Tags: vue.js, security, authentication, web-applications, frontend

So let's say we have a web app with a front end build in a Vue framework with some stuff like authentication being handled by Nuxt, or anything similar. Let's say we use some kind of bearer token for authentication.

I understand that somewhat secure comunication with back end is handled by these tokens that are being send with every request and the BE then determines that a user is allowed to get a response - that all happens server side.

But when we have a code like this (in Vue.js):

```
<div v-if="!$auth.loggedIn">Log in first!</div>
<div v-else>Super secret information</div>
```

The "secret information" is not displayed (or rendered) unless the user is signed in. But all the data is already fetched to the browser, right? There is no need for talking to a back end server once the user is authenticated to resolve the **if** condition. Can I somehow extract the "secret information" in the built javascript that's sent to my browser even if I'm not authenticated? If I really wanted to and dug really deep into the code? It's all already in there but just rerendered when the condition is met.

*The front end framworks have their own routing system with pages only accessible to authenticated users (behind auth middleware). Is this **just** how it works? Am i **just** supposed to fetch the "secret information" from the server too and know that anyone can display anything that's "hard coded" behind any front end auth middleware if they wanted to?*

Comment: Having all data in the browser is not secure. The `v-if` is just a gate to an authenticated call. All security checks are handled by server side. Vue is just a smart interface. Actually, forget about vue altogether: regardless of what tech renders your data, if you send it before the user is authenticated it can be intercepted. End of story. So the `v-if` is just a door to a call to fetch secured data, with appropriate credentials.

Answer (score 1):

> Can I somehow extract the "secret information" in the built javascript that's sent to my browser even if I'm not authenticated? If I really wanted to and dug really deep into the code?

Yes. You could if you wanted to. Please don't ever store critical data in the frontend. Your built files are just obfuscated but not unreadable.